# Java: calendar.setTimeInMillis() returns wrong HOUR_OF_DAY value

Tags: java, time, milliseconds

I am trying to convert my time in minutes to HH:MM. For example 418minutes = 6:58. I am using following code:

```
 long milli = PriemCas*60000;
 Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();       
 calendar1.setTimeInMillis(milli);
 int hours3 = calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 int minutes3 = calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

 System.out.println(hours3+":"+minutes3);
```

I get 7:58 when my variable PriemCas = 418 instead of 6:58. What could be wrong here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Daylight Saving Time? What's your timezone set to?

Comment: Given that the difference is exactly 1 hour, I'd check if something funny is going on with the time zones/DST settings...

Answer (score 14):

Create your Calendar with correct time zone:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: You should mark it as solved by accepting this answer. This way other people reading your question will know they'll find the right answer here.